# VSTO Office 365: Error when opening an Excel document

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

In my organisation, I have developped a VSTO application in Excel 2010 that is used by 8 users. The result of the deployment is an Excel document with c# code inside. The application is used to transmit data to the database. For the users, when they open a document that was used for a transmission (to avoid copying everything into a blank document).

Recently, we've upgraded from the operating system Windows 7 to Windows 10, from Microsoft Office 2010 to Microsoft Office 365 and from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2019. I didn’t have the bug with Windows 7, they get the following error message (in French):

**this document may not work as expected because the following control is missing: Feuil12. Data that needs this control will not be automatically displayed or updated and other custom features will not be available. Contact your administrator or the author of this document for help.**

[image]
[image]

Comment: What .NET version are you targeting?

Comment: The .NET version installed is 4.8

Comment: Also, in Visual Studio the target is .NET Framework 4.7.2 (Application-> Target framework)